# Handling interactive git commands from a magit extension

Tags: git, emacs, magit

I'm currently in the process of writing an extension to Magit, which will add the commands from the git plugin [Git Town](https://www.git-town.com/). You can see my current process [here](https://github.com/natecox/magit-town).

I've worked my way to a rough understanding of how to execute the commands I need to run and have a roughly functioning extension now. However, I've run into a wall that I can't seem to find a way over.

Certain commands, such as `git town sync`, will at times encounter either:

1. An error, such as pending configuration or conflict issues,
2. A confirmation asking questions about the issued command, such as what the parent branch is.

I have no idea how to collect, display, and respond to these situations using Magit, and currently have to fall back to a normal terminal. I've been scouring the docs trying to find out the correct way to handle this situation (which I feel to be common with git workflows) and have come up empty-handed.

So, my question is: how do I capture git command output, display it to the user, and allow them to respond, from within a magit extension?

Comment: Perhaps taking a look at magit-process-yes-or-no-prompt would give you an idea of how you could advise magit-process-filter.  For simple checks, though, it may be more convenient to do checking/handling in your extension (say asking for a parent branch) rather than letting things fall through to git town.